# Converting Mongo query to Laravel, nested elemMatch

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel

I have a query that runs correctly in Mongo, like such:

```
db.nested.find({'path':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:[25]}}}})
```

This correctly gets the data I'm looking for in a multidimensional array.

However, I am trying to convert this query to be used in Laravel using the laravel-mongodb (jenssegers) library, and it appears I cannot use more than one elemMatch on a single `where()`.

So doing something like:

```
DB::table('nested')->where('path','elemMatch', [25])->get();
```

Simply doesn't work because it's not looking far enough down the array.

How can I correctly rewrite the first query to work properly?

Comment: Tried `whereIn('path', [25])`?

Comment: @Tpojka Yes, unfortunately that returns an empty set.

Comment: @Tpojka What does work is `whereIn('path.0.1',[25])`, because it's querying a specific index. But I need it for all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution I found was just to use `whereRaw` instead:

```
whereRaw(['path'=>['$elemMatch'=>['$elemMatch'=>['$in'=>[25]]]]])
```

This works correctly.